# What would be the better way to send data from windows machine to remote server via API call?

Tags: mysql, windows

**The scenario:**
We have number of windows machines (with internet connection but no public IP) where  mysql server is running. It stores attendance data using biometric device.

**The problem:**
We want to send the attendance data periodically (30 minutes interval) to remote server via REST API. We have many windows machines, so the installation process should be simple.

What would be the better choices?

Here is what I have considered so far:

- Scheduled task that will call periodically an exe/bat file. Everything will be packed under  a msi installer.

Anticipating you kind suggestions, I've expertise on ruby/node. what would be the best choice to make the .exe  or should I go for bat/script?

Answer (score 0):

Use curl:

```
curl --data-binary @C:/path/file.bin http://example.com
```

If data is text:

```
curl --data @C:/path/file.txt http://example.com
```

Comment: Thanks,  but how can I achieve that scenario, where some script will be running 30 minutes interval that will read the mysql data and use your method to send data?